# Active Record validation :length error msg to show actual length?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a class that I am using a the validates method to check for length, and I want to inject the actual length into the error message. Is this possible?

Here is my current class where I am using the validation:

```
class Something
  validates :summary, :detail, :length => { 
    :in => 300..500,
    :too_short => "must have at least %{count} letters",
    :too_long => "must have at most %{count} letters"
  }
```

And the error message shows:

```
2 errors prohibited this job from being saved.

Summary must have at least 300 letters
Detail must have at least 300 letters
```

But I'd like to show:

```
...
Summary is only 250 letters and must have at least 300 letters
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your solution, you can pass custom validation

```
validate:summary_length

def summary_length 
  if self.summary.length < 10 && !self.summary.blank?
    errors[:base] << "is only #{self.summary.size} letters and must have at least 10 letters"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, seems to work for me:

```
class Something
    validates :summary,    
        :in => 300..500,
        :too_short => "summary is only #{summary.length} and must have at least %{count} letters"
        # etc.
    validates :detail,
        :in => 300..500,
        :too_short => "detail is only #{detail.length} and must have at least %{count} letters
       # etc.
```

Comment: I can't get that to work, and I don't think it would. In production, the variables would only be analyzed on start, but not on object instantiation, unless lambda is used (which I can't figure out how to in this context). But otherwise, I couldn't get mine to recognize 'summary'.